# RavenDb and MultiTenancy

Tags: ravendb, multi-tenant

I have looked and played around with RavenDb for a while and have started to look at MultiTenancy. Ayendes sample for multitenancy looks like this:

```
using(var store = new DocumentStore
{
    Url = "http://localhost:8080"
}.Initialize())
{
    store.DatabaseCommands.EnsureDatabaseExists("Brisbane");

    store.DatabaseCommands.EnsureDatabaseExists("Melbroune");
    store.DatabaseCommands.EnsureDatabaseExists("Sidney");

    using (var documentSession = store.OpenSession("Brisbane"))
    {
        documentSession.Store(new { Name = "Ayende"});
        documentSession.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

I don't know how each database is stored and hence the question: Will that work for large applications with a lot of tenants?

Comment: FYI - the 'EnsureDatabaseExists' will not work without a using directive for 'Raven.Client.Extensions'.  I had a very hard time finding this information.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

See the first and last paragraphs from the docs ([v2.5](http://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/2.5/csharp/server/multiple-databases) | [v3.0](http://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/3.0/csharp/server/administration/multiple-databases)).

> RavenDB's databases were designed with multi tenancy in mind, and are
> meant to support large number of databases on a single server. In
> order to do that, RavenDB will only keep the active databases open. If
> you access a database for the first time, that database will be opened
> and started, so the next request to that database wouldn't have to pay
> the cost of opening the database. But if a database hasn't been
> accessed for a while, RavenDB will cleanup all resources associated
> with the database and close it.
>
> That allows RavenDB to manage large numbers of databases, because at
> any given time, only the active databases are actually taking
> resources.

So yes it will support it and each database will be stored in a separate folder on disk.

Comment: To expand on that, by default we store the tenants in the Tenants\TenantName folder, adjacent to the main database Data folder.

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 basic options of implementing multi-tenancy (plus hybrid combinations):
[image]

All are good to go in RavenDB (the original question was about option #2). Of course, option #1 with fully isolated tenants is more secure but others are likely to become cheaper in the long run with option #3 being the most affordable out of the three (in the long run).

Check out these resources:

- A blog post "[Multi-tenant applications with NoSQL](https://alex-klaus.com/ravendb-yabt-multitenancy/)" that dives specifically in RavenDB implementations of multi-tenancy.
- [YABT project](https://github.com/ravendb/samples-yabt/) on GitHub that has implemented option #3.