# How to configure encryption of documents in ravendb in a multitenant scenario within IIS 7.5

Tags: encryption, ravendb, multi-tenant

Thanks to [Daniel Lang's blogpost](http://daniellang.net/document-level-encryption-in-ravendb/) we were able to encrypt our documents.

Since we are now in a multitenant situation([Multitenancy in RavenDb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364698/ravendb-and-multitenancy)) and deployed ravendb within `IIS 7.5` we want to encrypt all of the tenants.

Unfortunately we're getting a lot of errors (especially in the management studio):

`The remote server returned an error: NotFound.`

Our tenant databases are created, as we can see them on the file system. But within the management studio we cannot see them anymore.

To enable encryption we placed the encryption dll in the Plugins folder.

Do we need to make some extra configurations to get this to work?

**Edit: steps for reproduce:**

1. Clean instance of ravendb configured, IIS 7.5
2. Created an encryption dll, based on [Daniel Lang's blog post](http://daniellang.net/document-level-encryption-in-ravendb/)
3. Created a plugin folder and saved the encryption dll from step 2 in this folder
4. Go to management studio and create some sample data for the default database
5. Optional: create a tenant database and create some sample data

Comment: AndrewF,
Unless you take special steps, any bundles in the Plugins directory will be used by all the tenants.
Can you check the server log to see what the errors actually are?

Comment: unfortunatly the error log give me not much more details: `03/05/2012 13:16:04: Error on request`.

Comment: the real error is now showing itself: `Raven.Database.Server.HttpServer;Warn;Error on request;"System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Padding is invalid and cannot be removed.`

Comment: Can you post that to the mailing list? We a way to reproduce this? It looks like you are trying to use a different key, or something changed the content.